# Small shop fire safety for liquids/wood dust

Tags: safety

I am setting up a very basic wood shop. Basically a car garage. But I am away for it often for a few days at a time. It does have a fire alarm which of course depends on someone hearing it but I've never dealt with wood dust/woodworking flammable products before.

My first concern is about wood dust, I know it's extremely flammable and should not be left around. I have a vacuum so I vacuum and wipe down tables when I finish and throw it in the garbage. There is still very fine dust in the air but I don't think setting up a filtering system for a car garage I use a few times a week to make a few cuts makes sense. Is this a safety issue? If yes what is the most barebones solution?

Is leaving wood dust in the trash can a fire hazard and should be taken out daily?

There is no reason to assume there will be fire/sparks any more than in a typical house garage.

And second some liquids like Acetone and WD40 are flammable and can explode. Is there any point to keep them in a separate plastic container? Is fine wood dust landing on flammable containers create a higher fire hazard than if they are stored in a separate plastic container?

Again no reason to assume any source of flame or spark more than there is in a regular home.

I am concerned because I've never dealt with wood dust before.

Thank you!

Comment: I understand that exposions of fine particle material like sugar  typically occur in facilities with very poor house keeping / dirty  .

Comment: I would use a separate METAL container for the flammable liquids. "Properly" would be an expensive (but effective) flammable liquids storage cabinet. "Better than nothing" would be a steel storage cabinet or filing cabinet repurposed for storage. Those can often be picked up inexpensively used.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Is the benefit of metal that the fire starting inside of it is less likely to spread out? Or that a small fire outside of it will take longer time to get inside?